# How to fix The requested service DNS name could not be resolved - Azure Search

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cognitive-search

We are facing some issues with Azure Search.

The below error occurs exactly hourly.

"The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxxxxx.search.windows.net'"

and

"The requested service DNS name could not be resolved""

I don't know if is a Azure Search issue. Anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sometime due to high CPU usage causing DNS errors.

Most likely the other location you run the code on indeed does not have access to that remote location. I.e. in many corporate environment servers aren't allowed outside Internet access. You may want to try to ping/traceroute from that other server and if there's no access - configure router/firewall (open port etc.) or use proxy(setting the Proxy for the webclient)
Please check DNS configuration, and verify the DNS configuration is worked by "nslookup ********.core.windows.net".

Comment: Thanks @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT. This is an intermittent problem. Most of the time it works. The machine that tries to access the service of the azure search is a vm of the azure itself. I'll investigate the CPU problem.

Comment: If the issue persist and you believe your azure search cluster might be in an unhealthy state, please open up an azure ticket so one of our engineer can take a deeper look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Thanks @ramero-MSFT. I'll monitor in the next few days. We faced the same problem a few months ago, but it had stopped happening.  Today it happened again.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/ (we also experienced Azure DNS resolution issues earlier today)

Comment: Hi @DusanBajic. Thanks for your help. The day and time coincides with the moment that the problems happened. This must be the root cause. (5/13
Network Connectivity - Increased Latency).